# Wordpress image porfolio

Tags: php, wordpress

i am new to wordress 
i want to make image gallery from basic bootstrap template

i have this template for example:

```
<div class="row portfolio-images">
  <div class="col-md-3">
    <img src="">
     <a class="title" >title</a> 
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-3">
    <img src="" alt="">
    <a class="title" >title</a> 
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-3">
    <img src="" alt="">
    <a class="title" >title</a> 
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-3">
    <img src="" alt="">
    <a class="title" >title</a> 
  </div>
</div>
```

i want to know how to create image database or gallery in wordpress in the panel
and get the images url in an array and do something like this:

```
   <div class="row portfolio-images">
  <?php 
  for(the array){ ?>

      <div class="col-md-3">
        <img src="<?php echo image url ?> ">
         <a class="title" ><?php echo image title ?></a> 
      </div>
      <?php }?>

    </div>
```

because im lost right now and i need some guidence

Answer (score 0):

There are various plugins that you can use to generate the gallery. If you need to generate one without plugin then you can define a custom post type and then add images post on the relevant post type, which then can be listed on the required page.

Usually I use ACF plugin to generate custom field and then list it on the page. You can check it more here: http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/gallery/

Comment: i want to use my own styling and im also using mixitup for the portfolio 
i dont want something ready.